# Mac Hangs on boot, Macintosh HD partition intermittent failures

Tags: hard-drive, macos, disk-utility, partition, diskutil

I have the following problem: My 2016 MacBook Pro (El Capitan) hangs on boot. The progress bar loads to near completion, after that it stops. The laptop heats up and eventually shuts down.

What I need to do: Recover important data from the partition, then reinstall. No Time Machine saves are available.

What I attempted:

1. I booted into recovery partition (Using <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>  ) and launched Disk Utility. On first launch the Disk Utility app freezes. On second launch it works, displaying only the recovery partition.
2. Reset NVRAM, reboot and - Using the terminal, `diskutil list` command I get Macintosh HD partition listed.

   **However** If I run the command again, it is not longer listed. If I try to open Disk Utility app, its not listed there either. In order to see it again, I have to shut down, reset NVRAM, reboot into recovery mode and run the same command.

I do not understand this intermittent  behavior.

While I suspect disk failure, I am hoping that its simply an issue with the partition table.

This is what my output of `diskutil list` looks like:

(at boot)

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list    
/dev/disk0 (disk image):    
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER   
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk0    
   1:             Apple_HFS OS X Base System             2.0 GB     disk0s1

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):    
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER 
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                      *121.3 GB     disk1    
   1:                        EFI EFI                   209.7 MB     disk1s1    
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD          120.5 GB     disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD           650.0 MB     disk1s3

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):    
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER 
   0:                            Macintosh HD         +120.1 GB     disk2    
       Logical Volume on disk1s2    
       415411E3-C54B-44FC-BFE5-DF71AF55E7C1    
       Unencrypted
```

(and when I run the same command the second time)

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list    
/dev/disk0 (disk image):    
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER    
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk0    
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk0s1
```

Output of gpt show disk0

```
    start     size  index  contents
        0        1         PMBR
        1        1         Pri GPT header
        2       32         Pri GPT table
       34        6         
       40  3924400      1  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  3924440   262151         
  4186591       32         Sec GPT table
  4186623        1         Sec GPT header
-bash-3.2#
```

Comment: This could be the controller or the drive itself.  If you have access to another 2016 MBP, I would swap drives and see if the problem goes away.  It’s unlikely to be the GPT table and a format and reinstall is the best way to see if it’s hardware or software.  Issue the command `GPT show disk0` and post the output

Comment: As far as your data goes, I can’t stress the importance of a a Time Machine backup.  As you are now learning, this is going to be a *very, very expensive experience*.

Comment: Hello Allan, sorry for the long delay - we had a power outage.

Comment: @Allan As for the output, I have put it in the question text so its easier to read than in comment formating.

Comment: If you have access to a similar Mac you may be able to use Target Disk Mode.  https://support.apple.com/da-dk/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/mac

Comment: You have a MacBook Pro with a Fusion drive?  Where is the 2GB drive coming from?  The GPT table appears ok, but what I would do now is install macOS onto a USB drive, boot off that one, then download and install [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com) and start a recovery of your data.  It’s free to scan and see if there’s data but you’ll have to buy a license if you want to recover your data

Comment: Hello @Allan, the 2gb drive appears to be the recovery partition. Thank you for the recommendation, could you suggest a tutorial on how to do this? I have installed linux off USB drive, but how do I get a copy of macOS?